# Is this correct implementation, putting props inside this.setState and also please consider here I am using componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I know it is wrong to initialize props inside the state, but is there any other way of doing this ?

Is using useEffect() hook the only other way , than how to use it ?

```
componentDidMount (){
...
if(this.props.house.rent){
 this.setState({rent:this.props.house.rent});

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set default state values from props you can use the constructor.

Something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    rent: this.props.house.rent
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using useEffect :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(this.props.house.rent){
      this.setState({rent:this.props.house.rent});
    }
  }, []);
```